# Issue fetching data from Azure storage table

Tags: storage, azure-storage

We are trying to pull data from azure storage table using node.js application. This application uses table URI (along with URI it takes azure storage Accountname and Accesskey) to connect with storage account and queries the table entities.
Here is the format of table URI: https://azurestorageaccountname.table.core.windows.net 
The storage has been created on MSDN subscribed azure account.

Issue:  Getting message invalid table URI when code try to get table service instance.

```
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
   <code>ResourceNotFound</code>
   <message xml:lang="en-US">The specified resource does not exist. RequestId:a9d162ee-0002-003a-75f1-8361ff000000 Time:2014-10-31T06:02:51.0164254Z
   </message>
</error>
```

Please note I was able to pull the data using console application.
Please reply to me if any pointers or does anyone has faced such issue before.

Answer (score 0):

That error code would indicate that the table does not exist (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179438.aspx) - are you sure you have the table name correct and that that table does already exist? You can double check by trying to connect from a storage explorer such as the one in Visual Studio.

If that still appears to be correct maybe verify the table naming conventions etc (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179338.aspx) - note that the table names are case sensitive - and see if you can see anything else. You might also want to try running Fiddler and taking a look and ensuring that the URL and table name being sent to the service is what you expect.

Jason

Comment: Hi Jason, Thanks for reply. The table exists in store i double checked with azure management studio. and following the case sensitivity as well. is this something related to permissions?

Comment: Yes it could be. You aren't using SAS tokens are you? Can you send me code to repro at JAHOGG at Microsoft.com and then I will follow up. Don't include the account name / key in the code though.

Comment: Hi jason, i am not using SAS token in node.js application code.but following another approach wherein pulling data in "jason" format; which requires CORS enabled for azure table store and table SAS url.sending you both the codes on ur blog.Plz check and let me know ur inputs.

Comment: Hi jason..can u plz provide ur exact email where i can send the code...?

Comment: Can you confirm you have CORS set up correctly - see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/02/03/windows-azure-storage-introducing-cors.aspx for more information. If that still doesn't work my email (which I did include above is JAHOGG at Microsoft.com) - please include the sample code including your CORS permissions.

Comment: Hi Jason..my codes worked in different env wherein proxy is not blocked. Seems it's a proxy issue. i beleive once i map my machine's static IP with azure storage acoount's destination IP it should work. But i will send you the codes on mentioned email.